# ng-selected not working in angualr1.5.7

Tags: angularjs

I have a select like below where the defaultseleted data is being set using ng-selected in angular1.3.9. We have to upgrade the angular version to 1.5.7. Afetr upgrade ng-selected is not working. Default date is not being set. How do we resolve this.

```
<select id="rd" multiple data-ng-model="selDate" >
    <option ng-selected= "{{r.rDate == defaultDate}}" data-ng-repeat="r in releaseDates" value="{{r.rDate}}">{{r.description}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: could you create a small plunkr demonstrating the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ngOptions` rather than a repeat over the option element:

```
<select id="rd" multiple data-ng-model="selDate" ng-options="r.rDate as r.description for r in releaseDates"></select>
```

Then in your controller, simply set your `model` to the value you want to be selected:

```
$scope.selDate = [defaultDate]
```

Comment: I tried this way, but isn't working. See below. [{"releaseDate":"2015A01","description":"May 2015"}] is releaseDates. And my select is                                                                                                              <select id="rd" multiple data-ng-model="selreleaseDate"
   ng-options="r.releaseDate as r.description for r in releaseDates">
   </select>

Comment: @user1015388 -- Isn't this it/ http://plnkr.co/edit/xziqeszxHBGv9qDYOBa9?p=preview

Comment: from my backend I get selDate as 2015A01. this is a string and is not encapsulated as ["2015A01"]. Do I need to change this to this format. Even after I change, no good

Comment: Yes you need to change to the array format - verify that the string matches exactly what's in the array.

Comment: I got it fixed. Since I have multiple is select, i have to set the default selection in the form [{}]